# Using roslaunch to run rviz over distributed system

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I'm trying to run rviz over distributed system using roslaunch file.

Roslaunch file is as follows :-

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find urdf_tutorial)/display.launch">
<arg name="model" value="/home/sanket/ros_workspace/humanoid.urdf" />
</include>

<machine name="primary" address="172.16.2.159" user="san" default="false"/>

<machine name="secondary" address="172.16.3.182" user="san1" default="true" password="ai"/>



<node name="modelvisualisation" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" args="-d /home/sanket/ros_workspace/h1.vcg" />

</launch>
```

when i run above launch file i get following errors :-

```
started roslaunch server http://localhost:39646/
remote[172.16.3.182-0] starting roslaunch
remote[172.16.3.182-0]: creating ssh connection to 172.16.3.182:22, user[ai]
launching remote roslaunch child with command: [env ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.16.2.159 /opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh roslaunch -c 172.16.3.182-0 -u http://localhost:39646/ --run_id c51e4eb8-9b8b-11e2-b91e-848f69c0fd9c]
remote[172.16.3.182-0]: ssh connection created
remote[172.16.3.182-0]: Exception while registering with roslaunch parent [http://localhost:39646/]: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 498, in _register_with_server
code, msg, _ = server.register(name, self.uri)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
self.send_content(h, request_body)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
connection.endheaders(request_body)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
self.connect()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
 error: [Errno 111] Connection refused


 [172.16.3.182-0] killing on exit
 remote roslaunch failed to launch: secondary
```

can anyone help??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59755/using-roslaunch-to-run-rviz-over-distributed-system/) by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a nutshell, it looks like `secondary` cannot talk back to the roslaunch server on `primary`.

Try setting `ROS_HOSTNAME=172.16.2.159` on `primary` so that, when it spawns the roslaunch server, it does so with an externally accessible address (I assume you are running this launch file from `primary`). According to that output, it is being spawned on `localhost` which is obviously different for each machine (the first line `started roslaunch server http://localhost:39646/` tells you what address the roslaunch server is listening on).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on 2013-04-03**:
thanks..it solved my problem.